# Issues deploying meteor app to modulus

Tags: javascript, macos, meteor, deployment, modulus

Following something similar to this... http://stuart-85933.onmodulus.net/ and that exact one. Tried a bunch of things for an hour and I'm dying. Help please!

Thanks.

"Unable to connect to any application instances."

Here is my logs on modulus website

```
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ../../main
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
Now using node v0.10.41 (npm v3.9.6)
Found package.json: ./bundle/programs/server/package.json
Running command: npm start

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server
> node ../../main


assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
    at wrapPathFunction (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-92-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/mnt/app/.modulus/nvm/v0.10.41/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.41
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start: `node ../../main`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulus is currently working on adding compatibility for some of the                      newer Meteor releases i.e. Meteor 1.4. More information about this error can be found in the issues noted below. You can see updates on this issue here:[meteor github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4137), [meteor build runtime](https://github.com/onmodulus/docker-build-meteor/issues/25), [demeteorizer github issue](https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer/issues/191)

Edit: There is a workaround if you are still having trouble, but it is a little lengthy.  This workaround should work for any new version of Meteor that comes out, even versions that aren't working with the Meteor runtime yet.

1. Make sure the app runs locally
2. Install any unresolved modules
   i.e. if you get this message when running locally:

   ```
   Unable to resolve some modules:

   XYZ ...

   If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider         running:


   meteor npm install --save XYZ
   ```
3. Run demeteorizer

   ```
   $ npm install demeteorizer -g
   $ demeteorizer
   ```
4. Change directory to .demeteorized/bundle/programs/server/

   `$ cd .demeteorized/bundle/programs/server/`
5. Run npm install in that directory

   `$ npm install`
6. Edit the package.json in that directory after running 'npm install' and specify the correct node engine: i.e. node 4.4.7
7. Change directory to root of the bundle

   `$ cd ../../`
8. Make sure you are in the root of 'bundle,' and then zip the contents

   ```
   $ pwd
   /exampleDirectory/yourProject/.demeteorized/bundle
   ```

   - Zip contents of bundle

   `$ zip -r -X myProject.zip ./`
9. Move that zip to the root of your project directory (or a non hidden folder)
10. Go to your project dashboard at my.modulus.io

    - a. Stop your project
    - b. Change runtime to node.js in the
      'administration' panel
    - c. Confirm you have MONGO_URL and ROOT_URL
      specified in environment variables
    - d. Go back to 'home' of project
      dashboard, and upload / deploy the zip

Comment: haas this issue been resolved? I'm having the same trouble deploying 1.4 ..

Comment: @GerrievanWyk the issue has been resolved. You need to pass the node-version on with the deploy.
i.e. 
`$ modulus deploy -p MyProject --node-version 4`

Comment: modulus deploy command line gives me following error - error: unknown option `--node-version'

Comment: Try updating to the latest CLI then try deploying again using the node version flag.  ```$ npm install -g modulus@latest```